# Difference in Electric conductivity based on connection type?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Is there a difference in electrical conductivity dipending on the way the Material is connected?

For example, is there a difference between a copper wire connected to another one „via soldering“, one that just „touches“(twisting them together) the other wire and the conductivity „inside a single wire“?

Comment: Yes there is, but the difference is usually quite small, and only matters when the currents flowing through the joint are very large.

Comment: Have a read of [Analysis of ohmic losses due to solder and pressure interconnection and related interface resistances for solar cells](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1876610215008279/1-s2.0-S1876610215008279-main.pdf?_tid=91dc84d0-4211-48ce-a957-96ad7025c8f1&acdnat=1550304023_b37fc185de687e4f084ed02d9b0a138d).

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. The currents flowing through are minimal. Does it affect it somehow if the current is particularly small?